# R, whether all the elements of X are present in Y

Tags: r, vector

In R, how do you test for elements of one vector NOT present in another vector?

```
X <- c('a','b','c','d')
Y <- c('b', 'e', 'a','d','c','f', 'c')
```

I want to know whether all the elements of X are present in Y ? (TRUE or FALSE answer)

Comment: What is the expected behavior in the case that Carl Witthoft showed in his answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `setdiff`:

```
> setdiff(X, Y) # all elements present in X but not Y
character(0)

> length(setdiff(X, Y)) == 0
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: But see my answer with `vsetdiff` just in case

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, your answer where?

Comment: @beginneR  "Patience, grasshopper" :-) .  I posted the comment just prior to posting the answer - should be visible now

Comment: @CarlWitthoft, ok, sorry - I thought you meant an existing answer, perhaps on a different question. Nice answer by the way. We should figure out what the OP wants in such a case.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `all` and `%in%` to test if all values of `X` are also in `Y`:

```
all(X %in% Y)
#[1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is nice, almost like English :-)

Comment: Yes, quite easily understandable, indeed

Answer (score 2):

A warning about `setdiff` : if your input vectors have repeated elements,  `setdiff` will ignore the duplicates. This may or may not be what you want to do.

I wrote a package `vecsets` , and here's the difference in what you'll get. Note that I modified `X` to demonstrate the behavior.

```
 library(vecsets)
 X <- c('a','b','c','d','d')
 Y <- c('b', 'e', 'a','d','c','f', 'c')
 setdiff(X,Y)
   character(0)
 vsetdiff(X,Y)
[1] "d"
```

Comment: I think it is clear from the OP's question that duplicates do not matter, as he wants know whether *"all the elements of X are present in Y"*. Also, the term **[set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_(mathematics))** means that duplicates or order do not matter. So you should not use the term "set" in the name of your package/functions, since it will be very confusing.

Comment: @TMS Oddly enough, I interpret "all the elements of X" as meaning each element of the vector, not of the unique elements of the reduced algebraic set.  I'll stick with "set" in my function names despite the risk of confusion, since I view it as a companion, rather than a competitor, of algebraic set operations.